# Converting Strategy to Indicator

Tags: pine-script-v5

I am converting my Strategy into an Indicator, and one line of code is proving to be a challenge.

I only want a **Buy** or a **Sell** signal to appear, *if* the **Sell** or **Buy** Take/Stop was hit first. As in, I *do not* want it to Swing Trade into the other entry/direction until the current position is closed via the Take/Stop first.

So, it work in my strategy as per line 1 below:

1. ```
   if strategy.opentrades == 0
   ```
2. ```
      strategy.entry('Long', strategy.long, etc, etc)
   ```
3. ```
      strategy.entry('Short', strategy.short, etc, etc)
   ```

My question: **what is the Indicator line of code equivalent to what line 1. above does in the Strategy?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The 1) count the number of currently opened trades

You could use a custom integer counter variable that you increment whenever there is a entry signal and decrement whenever there is an exit signal (SL, TP)

```
var int count = 0

if (buy_signal or sell_signal)
    count := count + 1

if (exit_buy_signal or exit_sell_signal)
    count := count - 1
```